# Get Html H2 tag id value

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tags

I want to get h2 tag id value in the edit mode. Because if DetailsHeader is blank then I have to display error message.

```
<div class="modal-header">
<h2 class="tc_pageheader editableName" id="DetailsHeader"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: *Get it*?? Where, why, by what, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this site covers all languages and technologies—the bare minimum you should do is to tag your question correctly so it can be found by potential answerers (I suspect you are using JavaScript). Also, remember that we can't read your mind: you do know what you are working on but we don't. You should provide enough context about what you are trying to do, what you've done so far and how it failed to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var h2 = $(".modal-header > h2").attr("id");
```

I used jQuery because, I feel you are using BootStrap and it includes jQuery.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/nhp6d/

---

So to find if it is empty, you can use something like this:

```
if ($("#" + h2).text() == "")
  // Do something if empty!
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/nhp6d/1/